# Codingbat Logic-2 > roundSum answer is not very optimized

Tags: java, algorithm

It looks like I have answered the question here correctly: http://codingbat.com/prob/p186753

But my code seems too long to me and not very optimized. Can anyone suggest what can I do to make my code more succinct? Here is my code:

```
public int roundSum(int a, int b, int c) {
    return round10(a) + round10(b) + round10(c);
}

public int round10(int n) {
    String sumStr = null;

    if (n % 10 < 5) {
        int left = n / 10;
        String leftStr = Integer.toString(left);
        sumStr = leftStr + "0";
    }

    if (n % 10 >= 5) {
        int left = n / 10;
        int leftNew = left + 1;
        String sum = Integer.toString(leftNew);
        sumStr = sum + "0";
    }

    return Integer.parseInt(sumStr);
}
```

Comment: Instead of string manipulation, can you think of something you could do with the result of n%5 that would take you to the answer you want in round10?

Comment: not sure @jelford, can you elaborate or provide the answer so i can understand

Comment: Something like `roundedDown = n - (n%10);` then return either `roundedDown` or `roundedDown+10` (according to your existing logic)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution using another approach developed by myself. I basically used the nested ternary operator. Hopefully, it can be helpful and support you in your learning process.

```
public int roundSum(int a, int b, int c) {
    a = (a % 10 < 5 ) ? (a / 10) * 10 : ((a / 10) + 1) * 10;
    b = (b % 10 < 5 ) ? (b / 10) * 10 : ((b / 10) + 1) * 10;
    c = (c % 10 < 5 ) ? (c / 10) * 10 : ((c / 10) + 1) * 10;
    return a+b+c;
}
```